Identification of relative long exact sequence with Gysin sequence for de Rham cohomology
For a smooth manifold $M$ and a submanifold $S$ with inclusion $i:S\to M$, the relative de Rham cohomology is defined from the complex $\Omega^q(M,S):=\Omega^q(M)\oplus \Omega^{q-1}(S)$ with differential $d:\Omega^q(M,S)\to \Omega^{q+1}(M,S)$ given by $d(\omega,\theta)=(d\omega, i^*\omega- d\theta) $. Then there is a long exact sequence of the form $$\cdots\to H^q(M,S) \xrightarrow{\beta^*} H^q(M)\xrightarrow{i^*}H^q(S)\xrightarrow{\alpha^*}H^{q+1}(M,S)\to \cdots$$
where $\alpha^*(\theta)=(0,\theta)$ and $\beta^*(\omega,\theta)=\omega$ (Bott-Tu, Chapter 6).
Now let $\pi:V\to M$ be a rank $k+1$ vector bundle, $V^0$ the complement of the zero section, and $E\to M$ the associated sphere bundle (assuming that $V\to M$ has a fiberwise metric, for example). Then there is a Gysin exact sequence (Bott-Tu, Proposition 14.33) of the form $$ \cdots \to H^n(E)\xrightarrow{\pi_*} H^{n-k}(M)\xrightarrow{\wedge e}H^{n+1}(M)\xrightarrow{\pi^*}H^{n+1}(E)\to \cdots.$$
An exercise of Bott-Tu asks to show that this sequence can be identified with the long exact sequence of $(V,V^0)$.
We already know that $H^*(V)\cong H^*(M)$ and $H^*(V^0)\cong H^*(E)$ via inclusions. Now we need a suitable map between $H^{n-k}(M)$ and $H^{n+1}(V,V^0)$, and then use five lemma to show that it is an isomorphism, and conclude that the two sequences can be identified.
I have three candidates:

$H^{n-k}(M)\to H^{n+1}(V,V^0)$ defined by $\omega\mapsto (\pi^*(\omega \wedge e),0)$ where $e$ is the Euler class.

$H^{n-k}(M)\to H^{n+1}(V,V^0)$ defined by $\omega\mapsto (\pi^*(\omega \wedge e),(-1)^{n-k+1}(\pi^*\omega)\wedge \psi)$ where $e$ is the Euler class and $\psi$ is the global angular form.

$H^{n+1}(V,V^0)\to H^{n-k}(M)$ defined by $(\omega,\theta)\mapsto \pi_*\theta$.


The maps of 1 and 2 are seen to be well-defined, but commutativity (for the five lemma) don;t seem obvious. The map 3 is not even well-defined, even though commutativity can be verified. Should I need another map between $H^{n-k}(M)$ and $H^{n+1}(V,V^0)$?

The map should be the Thom isomorphism.
